# Add animation to verold model object

Tags: javascript, three.js, verold

I'm trying to use [verold](http://www.verold.com/learn/articles/verold-api-cheat-sheet-22) to animate 3d models in a script. However, I'm having trouble understanding the corret usage of the verold API components.

I have a model loaded to my scene, and a script attached as an attribute of that model. I also have a keyframe animation attribute, which is set up to not auto play.

My goal here is to be able to start a particular animation when the user clicks a button. I can see the model object when I use the following code

```
PlayAnimation.prototype.init = function() {
// this.veroldEntity is available here but the Three.JS data isn't loaded yet
cObject = this.veroldEntity;

};
```

But I'm unsure of how to use the playanimation(loop,startTime,save,fn) function.

So my questions are: 
1. Is this the correct way to start an animation in a script?
2. If so, could someone show me the proper way to use this, i.e what are the save and fn parameters?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get a reference to the Keyframe Animation component that you want to control via script. You can use `getComponentsByScriptName()` to get the Keyframe Animation component(s) attached to an entity:

```
PlayAnimation.prototype.init = function() {
  var animationsById = this.getEntity().getComponentsByScriptName("Keyframe Animation");

  this.animations = [];

  for (var id in animationsById) {
    this.animations.push(animationsById[id]);
  }
};
```

If a single Keyframe Animation component is attached to the entity, then `this.animations[0]` will refer to it. Next, you can play the animation:

```
this.animations[0].play();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to trigger an animation from your component. You can either use the animation API, or you can setup an EventHandler in the UI.

The EventHandler is the easy way:

http://www.verold.com/learn/articles/using-the-verold-loader-73

In fact, if there's one post you should look at to understand how Verold works, I'd say take a look at that one. It sums up nicely the most common way of working with the Verold API. Build your interface in HTML/CSS, and fire events from your app into Verold. Then do as much as you can using our built-in components and editor. There's a lot more to the Verold API, not to mention what you can do by getting a handle to the Three.js renderer underneath, but you can achieve a lot using events.

I will let Ian answer how to use the animation API. Use the API directly if you want to drive more complex interactivity, for example if you want custom animation blending.